# Collecting prometheus metrics from a separate port using flask and gunicorn with multiple workers

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, gunicorn, prometheus

I run a small flask application with gunicorn and multiple worker processes on kubernetes. I would like to collect metrics from this application with prometheus, but the metrics should only be accessible cluster internally on a separate port (as this required in our current setting).

For one gunicorn worker process I could use the `start_http_server` fucntion from the python client library to expose metrics on a different port than the flask app.

A minimal example may look like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Counter

NUM_REQUESTS = Counter("num_requests", "Example counter")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    NUM_REQUESTS.inc()
    return 'Hello, World!'

start_http_server(9001)
```

To start the app do the following:

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8082 -w 1 app:app
```

However this only works for one worker process.

In the documentation of the client library is also a [section](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#multiprocess-mode-gunicorn) on how to use prometheus and gunicorn with multiple worker processes by specifying a shared directory for the worker processes as an environment variable where metrics are written to (`prometheus_multiproc_dir`).

So following the documentation the above example for  multiple workers would be:

A gunicorn config file:

```
from prometheus_client import multiprocess

def worker_exit(server, worker):    
    multiprocess.mark_process_dead(worker.pid)
```

The application file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from prometheus_client import Counter

NUM_REQUESTS = Counter("num_requests", "Example counter")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    NUM_REQUESTS.inc()
    return "[PID {}]: Hello World".format(os.getpid())
```

To start the app do:

```
rm -rf flask-metrics/
mkdir flask-metrics
export prometheus_multiproc_dir=flask-metrics
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8082 -c gunicorn_conf.py -w 3 app:app
```

However in this setting I don't really know how to accesses the metrics stored in flask-metrics on a separate port. Is there way to get this done?

I am a bit new to these things, so if I am approaching the problem in the wrong way I am also happy for advice what would be the best way to address my case.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain as to how you solved this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you would want to do here is start up a separate process just to serve the metrics. Put the  `app` function in https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#multiprocess-mode-gunicorn in an app of its own, and make sure that `prometheus_multiproc_dir` is the same for both it and the main application.

Answer (score 1):

I used Prometheus_flask_exporter to do that.

My gunicorn config file was like this-

```
from prometheus_flask_exporter.multiprocess import GunicornPrometheusMetrics

hostname = "0.0.0.0"
portname = 8080

def when_ready(server):
    GunicornPrometheusMetrics.start_http_server_when_ready(8000)

def child_exit(server, worker):
    GunicornPrometheusMetrics.mark_process_dead_on_child_exit(worker.pid)
```

The wsgi file included-

```
from prometheus_flask_exporter import PrometheusMetrics

# an extension targeted at Gunicorn deployments for prometheus scraping in flask applications
from prometheus_flask_exporter.multiprocess import GunicornPrometheusMetrics

application = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
CORS(application)

health = HealthCheck(application, "/healthcheck")
metrics = PrometheusMetrics(application)
metrics = GunicornPrometheusMetrics(application)
```